# Is it faster/traditional to use append vs cons and reverse in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

When building a list recursively in Scheme I see two types of examples scattered about the internet. One in which a new value is appended with `append` every iteration. The other in which a new value is prepended every iteration with `cons` then after the list is complete `reverse` is called once.

My gut instinct is that the latter is faster, but if the Scheme interpreter cached an end of list pointer or is doing some other optimization then the former would be just as fast and more readable. If the interpreter is doing this optimization, is it guaranteed to be available in all interpreters?

Comment: "ust as fast and more readable."  Except that experienced coders unfamiliar with the new optimization would keep stopping to say "this shouldn't have been done this way". And append *copies* the first list, so just keeping a pointer to the end of another list isn't an option.  Plus, you can always cons and save the result.  You can't save a pointer to the last cons of an empty list, though.

Comment: see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons),  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+modulo+cons), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+head+sentinel) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970021/understanding-loop-macro-expansion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `cons` is always preferred. Using `append` is terribly inefficient, as it will always traverse the list to the end just to add a new element there, whereas `cons` adds the element at the beginning. There is no such thing as a pointer to the end of the list, so the optimization you suggested isn't performed at all.

When building large lists element by element this matters a lot, as `cons` is an `O(1)` operation, whereas `append` is `O(n)` *for each new element added*, degrading to `O(n^2)` complexity! (for a great analogy, see: [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm)). In the end, is much cheaper to simply add elements at the beginning and if necessary `reverse` the list at the end, achieving `O(n)` complexity.